# Signature does not match s3 uploading object

Tags: javascript, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to implement an unploading of image to amazon s3 using only rest api. I've seen their docs but the problem is I'm only using temporary credential which will expire for about an hour. Below is the response

```
{
 accessKey: "mykey"
 secretKey: "mysecret"
 token: "mytemptoken"
 expiry: 1381128021000
}
```

My policy

```
POLICY_JSON = { "expiration": "2013-12-03T12:29:27.000Z",
            "conditions": [
                    ["eq", "$bucket", this.get('bucket')],
                    ["starts-with", "$key", this.get('key')],
                    {"acl": this.get('acl')},
                    {"success_action_redirect": this.get('successActionRedirect')},
                    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", this.get('contentType')]
            ]
          };
```

Here what I tried so far:
Using chrome advance rest client I entered this url: https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/avatars/test@domain.com with headers of

```
Authorization: AWS mykey:CXp5qqO6q552VDYUI0aBlSd/pTs=
x-amz-security-token: mytemptoken
x-amz-date: Mon, 07 OCt 2013 06:20:37 GMT
```

The result was: 403 Forbidden and its saying SignatureDoesNotMatch. Does anyone able to accomplish uploading of object using only Rest Api of s3 (not using of SDK's). The client asked me if its possible to build it using only javascript. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Should you not sign the content?  [Check this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html) how to sign.  After signing you have to pass the signature value in the Authorization header.

Authorization: AWS AWSAccessKeyId:Signature

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. yes, i included the signature on my authorization header. I generated my signature using this: var policyBase64 = Base64.encode(JSON.stringify(POLICY_JSON));
var signature = b64_hmac_sha1(secret, policyBase64);

Comment: nope, it still saying SignatureDoesNotMatch. Could you take a look at my policy json? Is there anything missing on my policy. I'm using temporary credentials so I added x-amz-security-token on my header.

Comment: Why are you encoding and signing policy?  Did you try these steps `http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html`

Comment: im sorry, I'm reading it now. I'm having difficulty understanding a canonical request. Right now I'm using Chrome advance rest client to perform http request to amazon. How do I perform canonical req there?

Comment: I think you cannot use that directly to calculate signature unless you have a tool outside to calculate signature and add that manually to chrome advanced rest client.  Writing httpclient is very easy.  You can use Java HttpUrlConnection and call the http methods.

Comment: Sorry I am in office. Chat is blocked in office.  Please note I am not an expert in AWS.  I recently got training in AWS and based on that I am answering your questions.

Comment: Yup, I have a script that calculate the signature then with the calculated signature I then added it to my header request "Authorization" but it still not working. If only I could make a successful S3 Rest Api request through Advance Rest Client then I maybe could move forward. Y__Y.